# Create a loop for variable?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I have the below code. In total I will need the output from 40 different tickers. However, I am facing issues trying to code a loop as it is very difficult to understand. This will prevent me from having to repeat the whole block of code 40 times. Appreciate your help. I have tried to create and watch tutorials on how to loop but none of them seem to be able to solve my issue.

```
var t1g = 0
var t1r = 0
if barstate.isnew
    t1g := 0
    t1r := 0
gcondition1 = ticker1 >= ulevel
gcondition2 = ticker1 > ticker1[1] and ticker1 < ulevel and ticker1 > llevel
rcondition1 = ticker1 <= llevel
rcondition2 = ticker1 < ticker1[1] and ticker1 > llevel and ticker1 < ulevel
t1g := gcondition1 or gcondition2 ? 1 : 0
t1r := rcondition1 or rcondition2 ? 1 : 0

and at the end of it all, I would want to sum the total of each fulfilled condition for all tickers such as

totalgreen = t1g + t2g + t3g +...+ t40g
totalred = t1r + t2r + t3r +...+ t40r

The changes for each ticker will be
t1g -> t2g -> ... -> t40g
t1r -> t2r -> ... -> t40r
ticker1 -> ticker2 -> ... -> ticker40
```